# Getting "source exhausted prematurely" when inflating gzip HTTP response body

Tags: android, gzip, okhttp, okio

I get this following error when I'm trying to make a HTTP call with okhttp:

```
W/System.err: java.io.EOFException: source exhausted prematurely
W/System.err:     at okio.InflaterSource.read(InflaterSource.java:83)
W/System.err:     at okio.GzipSource.read(GzipSource.java:80)
W/System.err:     at okio.Buffer.writeAll(Buffer.java:1135)
W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSource.readString(RealBufferedSource.java:199)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.ResponseBody.string(ResponseBody.java:176)
W/System.err:     at com.ethanwang.andplay.OKHttpTaskTag.doInBackground(OKHttpTaskTag.java:41)
W/System.err:     at com.ethanwang.andplay.OKHttpTaskTag.doInBackground(OKHttpTaskTag.java:20)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I was only able to find this related issue: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2193 but I have made sure that `Content-Length` is the correct length of the response body. Here is my logged okhttp request and response:

Request:

```
    I/System.out: INFO: Sending request http://test.essaybot.com/msg/tag_search on Connection{test.essaybot.com:80, proxy=DIRECT@ hostAddress=test.essaybot.com/34.208.145.50:80 cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1}
I/System.out: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
I/System.out: Content-Length: 33
I/System.out: Host: test.essaybot.com
I/System.out: Connection: Keep-Alive
I/System.out: Accept-Encoding: gzip
I/System.out: User-Agent: okhttp/3.11.0
```

Response:

```
I/System.out: INFO: Received response for http://test.essaybot.com/msg/tag_search in 62.2ms
I/System.out: Cache-Control: no-cache
I/System.out: Content-Encoding: gzip
I/System.out: Content-Length: 139
I/System.out: Content-Type: application/json
I/System.out: Set-Cookie: PHP_SESSION=0Q4rZJplDjrUNB4ZbWAG; Path=/; Max-Age=2592000
I/System.out: Set-Cookie: VISITOR_ID=65xGr53M1xM0waK8; Path=/; Max-Age=31536000
I/System.out: Date: Wed, 29 Aug 2018 20:45:06 GMT
I/System.out: INFO: Received response body bytes: 
I/System.out:  [31, -117, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 44, -51, 65, 10, -62, 64, 12, 5, -48, -85, 72, -42, 93, -72, -18, -50, -91, 103, 16, -111, -23, 52, -83, 31, 66, -90, 100, 50, -94, -120, 119, -105, 116, -70, 9, 47, -16, -109, -1, 37, 54, 123, 104, -95, -15, 60, -112, 113, 109, -30, 52, -34, -24, 50, -65, 88, -67, 25, -45, 16, 70, -34, 97, 30, 115, 49, -28, 20, -128, 9, -108, 107, 80, -33, 96, -1, -12, 12, 22, 100, 36, 57, 93, -43, 89, 4, 43, 107, -65, -34, -74, 61, 58, -49, -56, -114, -94, -31, 86, -35, -110, -32, -8, 54, -23, 20, 88, -95, 107, -81, 101, 115, -44, 99, -109, 92, -98, 69, 66, 21, -119, -18, -65, 63, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1] 
I/System.out:  With length: 139
```

The server works perfectly fine with our web and iOS ends. It also worked fine with android until about two months ago, when it suddenly stopped working with no network changes. What else could cause this error?

-------------------------------------- updated --------------------------------------

[image]
It seems like the data in buffer is readable since from the debugger above there is readable text (`[size=185 text={"err_no":0,"result":["Adventure","Advice","Art","Africa","Airli…]`) annotated after the buffer variable. Also, the data from the debugger is different from the logged data:

```
data = {byte[8192]@4418} 
 0 = 123
 1 = 34
 2 = 101
 3 = 114
 4 = 114
 5 = 95
 6 = 110
 7 = 111
 8 = 34
 9 = 58
 10 = 48
 11 = 44
 12 = 34
 13 = 114
 14 = 101
 15 = 115
 16 = 117
 17 = 108
 18 = 116
 19 = 34
 20 = 58
 21 = 91
 22 = 34
 23 = 65
 24 = 100
 25 = 118
 26 = 101
 27 = 110
 28 = 116
 29 = 117
 30 = 114
 31 = 101
 32 = 34
 33 = 44
 34 = 34
 35 = 65
 36 = 100
 37 = 118
 38 = 105
 39 = 99
 40 = 101
 41 = 34
 42 = 44
 43 = 34
 44 = 65
 45 = 114
 46 = 116
 47 = 34
 48 = 44
 49 = 34
 50 = 65
 51 = 102
 52 = 114
 53 = 105
 54 = 99
 55 = 97
 56 = 34
 57 = 44
 58 = 34
 59 = 65
 60 = 105
 61 = 114
 62 = 108
 63 = 105
 64 = 110
 65 = 101
 66 = 115
 67 = 34
 68 = 44
 69 = 34
 70 = 65
 71 = 110
 72 = 120
 73 = 105
 74 = 101
 75 = 116
 76 = 121
 77 = 34
 78 = 44
 79 = 34
 80 = 65
 81 = 114
 82 = 116
 83 = 105
 84 = 102
 85 = 105
 86 = 99
 87 = 105
 88 = 97
 89 = 108
 90 = 32
 91 = 73
 92 = 110
 93 = 116
 94 = 101
 95 = 108
 96 = 108
 97 = 105
 98 = 103
 99 = 101
 100 = 110
 101 = 99
 102 = 101
 103 = 34
 104 = 44
 105 = 34
 106 = 65
 107 = 112
 108 = 112
 109 = 115
 110 = 34
 111 = 44
 112 = 34
 113 = 65
 114 = 100
 115 = 100
 116 = 105
 117 = 99
 118 = 116
 119 = 105
 120 = 111
 121 = 110
 122 = 34
 123 = 44
 124 = 34
 125 = 65
 126 = 117
 127 = 115
 128 = 116
 129 = 114
 130 = 97
 131 = 108
 132 = 105
 133 = 97
 134 = 34
 135 = 44
 136 = 34
 137 = 65
 138 = 105
 139 = 114
 140 = 98
 141 = 110
 142 = 98
 143 = 34
 144 = 44
 145 = 34
 146 = 65
 147 = 103
 148 = 105
 149 = 110
 150 = 103
 151 = 34
 152 = 44
 153 = 34
 154 = 65
 155 = 100
 156 = 118
 157 = 101
 158 = 114
 159 = 116
 160 = 105
 161 = 115
 162 = 105
 163 = 110
 164 = 103
 165 = 34
 166 = 44
 167 = 34
 168 = 65
 169 = 108
 170 = 99
 171 = 111
 172 = 104
 173 = 111
 174 = 108
 175 = 34
 176 = 44
 177 = 34
 178 = 65
 179 = 115
 180 = 105
 181 = 97
 182 = 34
 183 = 93
 184 = 125
 185 = 0
 186 = 0
 187 = 0
 188 = 0
 189 = 0
 190 = 0
 191 = 0
 192 = 0
 193 = 0
 194 = 0
 195 = 0
 196 = 0
 197 = 0
 198 = 0
 199 = 0
```

----------------------- update ------------------------

I used the debugger to trace the problem and it seems like the gzipped response was decompressed twice. As shown in the pictures attached, read in InflaterSource.java is called twice. The exception is thrown at the second time it's being decompressed.

[image: The first time <code>read</code> is called]
The first time `read` is called

[image: The second time <code>read</code> is called]
The second time `read` is called, the exception is thrown

Comment: What is `Segment.SIZE` value in your example?

Answer (score 3):

I had this error on a retrofit GET request to a random site,I added

```
 @Headers("Accept-Encoding: identity")
```

to fix it.

> identity
>       Indicates the identity function (i.e. no compression, nor modification). This value is always considered as acceptable, even if not present.

Answer (score 2):

The server data is corrupt. It's supposed to contain a gzip trailer to indicate the end of the stream and that's missing.

Comment: How could you tell the gzip trailer is missing? I'm not sure if the way I logged the response body was correct: `byte[] responseBodyByteArray = response.body().bytes(); 
        String responseBodyByteArrayString = Arrays.toString(responseBodyByteArray);`

Comment: The last four bytes of the stream should be it's length in little endian. The four bytes before that should be a checksum. Confirm by decompressing the compressed stream with the gunzip tool, or by stepping through the GzipSource code in a debugger.

Comment: I used the debugger and the data seem to be different from the byte string I previously logged. Also, it looks like the buffered data is readable since there's readable text after the Buffer variable. I updated my question with a screenshot and data from the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code for getting inputstream. I hopeful it work for you.

```
private static String getResponseString(Response response) {
    try {
        InputStream inputStream;
        String contentEncodingHeader = response.header("Content-Encoding");
        if (contentEncodingHeader != null && contentEncodingHeader.equals("gzip")) {
            // Read the zipped contents.
            inputStream = new GZIPInputStream(response.body().byteStream());
        } else {
            // Read the normal contents.
            inputStream = response.body().byteStream();
        }

        // Create and return buffered reader.
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        // Read stream.
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line.trim());
        }
        // Close everything.
        response.body().close();
        inputStream.close();
        br.close();
        return sb.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return "";
    }
}
```